# curl_init and curl_exec: extract table?

Tags: php, curl

hey guys,
i'm completely new to cURL - i've never used it before.
If i paste the following two lines inside of my sidebar ...

```
<?php
    $objCUrl = curl_init("http://www.domain.com/hptool/weather_v1.php?cid=43X1351&l=en");
    curl_exec($objCUrl);
?>
```

...i get two divs and a table inserted into my page. Is there a method where i can kind of inspect everything that gets loaded with this curl_init function? I just want to get specific stuff on my page inserted and not everything? E.g. i only want to insert the table but not the two divs that get inserted into my page.

I know i could simply hide them with css, but i'm just curious.

Comment: You could use file_get_contents for this simple case :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the result to a string instead of outputting it.

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/hptool/weather_v1.php?cid=43X1351&l=en';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$str = curl_exec($curl);
```

Now you can pull whatever you need out of `$str` and display that.

First place you should go is [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) for how to use a function/library.

Comment: I am missing the obligatory "Thou shalt not parse (X)HTML with a reg-ex" hint. +1 Anyways :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another common method is to use an output buffer around your `curl_exec($objCUrl)` call.

```
ob_start();
curl_exec($objCUrl); 
$str = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: No need for this kind of heavy artillery, when curl already has internal mechanisms to accomplish this, AND capture the full request state, rather than just the output (which you'd need for debugging/error handlign).